# How to keep icomoon icon at middle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to keep the icomoon icon `icon-uniE610` at the middle like the **below image**
[image]

But the way I did keeps the icon at the top

**Below image** [image]is the way I did

This is my icomoon style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?ktnun7');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefixktnun7') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?ktnun7') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?ktnun7') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?ktnun7#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-search:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
.icon-users:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-lock:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-cogs:before {
    content: "\e603";
}
.icon-bubbles:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-pawn:before {
    content: "\e605";
}
.icon-box-add:before {
    content: "\e606";
}
.icon-signup:before {
    content: "\e607";
}
.icon-equalizer:before {
    content: "\e608";
}
.icon-bars:before {
    content: "\e609";
}
.icon-disk:before {
    content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-user:before {
    content: "\e60b";
}
.icon-stackoverflow:before {
    content: "\e60d";
}
.icon-store:before {
    content: "\e60e";
}
.icon-user2:before {
    content: "\e60c";
}
.icon-trash:before {
    content: "\e60f";
}
.icon-uniE610:before {
    content: "\e610";
    font-size:50px;
    color:black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and this is my html code

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <img src="http://www.computerhope.com/logo.gif" alt="Logo"  class="round"/> user
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 ">Recently purchased
                       <div id="slideshow">
                               <span class="images">
                                       <div class="col-md-3"><div class="box">
                                               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract" />
                                                       <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                                               <p>Review</p>
                                                       </span>
                                           </div></div>
                                       <div class="col-md-3"><div class="box">
                                               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/food" />
                                                       <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                                               <p>Review</p>
                                                       </span>
                                           </div></div>
                               </span>

                                       <a class="next icon-uniE610" href="#">Next</a>
                       </div>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/vMYKY/46/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following CSS,

```
.next {
height: 100%;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#slideshow{
    display:table;
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/49/)**